# Radio buttons in Vuejs 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a small application in `VueJS 2.0` and I'm using Inspinia premium admin template, where I'm having a radio buttons something like this:

```
<div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-white active"> 
        <input type="radio" v-model="taskTime" value="7" name="taskTime"> Week 
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> 
        <input type="radio" v-model="taskTime" value="30" name="taskTime"> Month 
    </label>
</div>
```

When any of the buttons being selected or if `taskTime` data is changed I'm calling a function, so for this I've watch function:

```
watch: {
    taskTime(newValue) {
        console.log('clicked');

    }
}
```

I'v properly defined v-model/data in my data set

```
data() {
    return {
        taskTime: ''
    }
},
```

JSFiddle in my case: https://jsfiddle.net/60q14y26/

I don't know why it is not working, I guess something is preventing from executing this. Help me out with these.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, if you have a missing curly closing bracket for data in your local code. But in the jsfiddle you provided, that was the issue. In the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60q14y26/1/), watch works fine.

Comment: @Pradeepb You are right this thing was missed by me, but the problem is when I implement the same on my theme. The same code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="app">
  <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
    taskTime {{ taskTime }}
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-white active"> 
        <input type="radio" v-model="taskTime" value="7"  name="taskTime"> Week 
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> 
        <input type="radio" v-model="taskTime" value="30" name="taskTime"> Month 
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      taskTime: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    taskTime(newValue) {
      console.log('clicked');
    }
  }
})
```

This is working snippet. You missed one "}" in your fiddle ;)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uohnsyfq/)

[version with counter](https://jsfiddle.net/pzw4ubf1/)

And one more thing: your build system can remove console.log from final code.

Comment: That was the missed by me, but the problem is not that, I know it is working as we draft out the normal way in fiddle, but I'm not getting the appropriate result when I implement the same on my theme.

Comment: I don't know much about Inspinia. I can't find anything about Vue. Are you using static html from that product?